# Is there scope issues if I move one element from one container to another?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router

Considering that you have this situation:

```
<div class="site-frame">
    <div class="auxiliary"></div>

    <div class="main" ui-view>
        <div class="componentA">
        </div>

        <div class="componentB" move-to=".auxiliary" breakpoints="1,2,3,4">
            <!-- CONTENTS OF componentB -->
        </div>

        <div class="componentC">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The element `.componentB` has a directive called `move-to` which does simply move the contents of this element, collecting them with a jQuery children wildcard selector (like `var contents = $('.componentB').find('> *');`), when any of those breakpoints, defined on the `breakpoints` directive (those numbers are the indexes of one array, that keeps the breakpoints measurements) are currently occurring.

When some breakpoint of that directive is active, the DOM change to this:

```
<div class="site-frame">
    <div class="auxiliary">
        <!-- CONTENTS OF componentB -->
    </div>

    <div class="main" ui-view>
        <div class="componentA">
        </div>

        <div class="componentB" move-to=".auxiliary" breakpoints="1,2,3,4">
        </div>

        <div class="componentC">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is a responsive mechanism is being used in a static version of one website that I'm dealing with. What I need is to know if there's flaws with the scope inheritance, event broadcasting, state controller, which is being related to the `div.main`, which is itself a sibling of the `div.auxiliary`.

Wondering on how angular does it's job, I suppose that the JS logic layer keeps relations between the DOM element being referenced on some scope. Mainly on directive scopes, using `link()` functions, which are `post-link()` by nature so DOM manipulation is more secure, because the link was already made.

Keep in mind that I keep references of the `.componentB` contents inside the `link()` function, while listening to the scope `$destroy` event, to clear things up, avoiding memory leaks. Also because this system listens to `$window.on('resize')` to find out which is the current breakpoint and, during the navigation, it's possible that the contents of my example can be moved between their original container and the auxiliary one.

So, the question is: if I move one element through DOM, even outside it's ui-view parent, it's safe to keep counting on variable updates on data-bindings, inheritances, and so on?

I'm asking this before implementing because of the huge size of the application, and as always on production-wise runnings, there was no room to discuss this before...

## Edit 1:

Temporarily, this CodePen has more chances: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JXPvBE?editors=0010

The code is doing what I need, but I need to test it inside the final app.

Comment: Seems like it wouldn't be hard to create a reasonably simple test case for this yourself. Without knowing all the scopes involved and how the overall application works the question iself is really broad

Comment: I'm doing this right, will update the question with one plunker. But, indeed, with the application I'm working with, this may face several problems.

Comment: About the broad look of the question it's indeed, because this is supposed to work with any component, or element, inside of the application, both directives or state related controller code, you know...

Comment: Still far too many unknowns though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I was developing other tasks, the solution posted on the **Edit 1** of the question pointed over a good way to deal with this.

While some doubts about the persistance of the original controller, of the parent element, were somehow a leak on this situation, which means, for example, that other updates on the models had the possibility to not be affected with the changes, until now, no problems were noticed.

Perhaps with other situations it can fail, but for now, it's working well:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JXPvBE?editors=0010

On the CodePen, on the beginning of the directive `move-to`, the compile function, at the pre-link phase, keeps an reference to the element in case, to manipulate it using it's original form, before angular process it's directives too (like `ng-repeat`), and so we will not be dealing with those angular comments that limit the place of it's directives:

```
<!-- ng-repeat: x in collection -->
<li class="repeated-element">
    ...
</li>
<!-- end ng-repeat: x in collection -->
```

It's is indeed a good way to deal with some responsive issues, were no room left for some functionalities on the SPA and you need to place them in a auxiliary container, that covers the entire page and properly places those elements that need more attention, like the native apps on mobile phones, with side panels.+